# i am not able to load JBBarChartView into my view? I cannot see anything in the view

Tags: objective-c, ios-charts, jbchartview

I have created a view in the header file. import the BarChartView in the header file as well.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet JBBarChartView *barChartView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
JBBarChartView *barChartView = [[JBBarChartView alloc] init];
barChartView.dataSource = self;
barChartView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:barChartView];
}
```

I added some built in methods which gives the property to JBBarChart

```
   - (UIColor *)barSelectionColorForBarChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView
{
    return [UIColor greenColor]; // color of selection view
}
- (BOOL)slideNavigationControllerShouldDisplayLeftMenu
{
    return YES;
}
- (UIColor *)barChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView colorForBarViewAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [UIColor greenColor];
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfBarsInBarChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView
{
    return 4;
}
- (CGFloat)barChartView:(JBBarChartView *)barChartView heightForBarViewAtAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return 100.0;
}
```

Any Help would be highly appreciated, there is still nothing in the view

Comment: Quoting from JBChartView readme: 

"Lastly, ensure you have set the frame of your barChartView & call reloadData at least once:

barChartView.frame = CGRectMake( ... );
[barChartView reloadData];"

You didn't set a frame for your chart view, or at least you are not showing that part of your code.

Comment: yes agreed EDUsta, and other thing was problem with the library heightForBarViewAtAtIndex, AtAt was causing the problem as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to be update one line only

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
JBBarChartView *barChartView = [[JBBarChartView alloc] init];
barChartView.dataSource = self;
barChartView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:barChartView];//Update this line
}
```

Comment: Yatish Agrawal, thanks for the answer but it didnt worked it out.